# JS commands not recognized in an external file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm tring to use the command `innerHTML` to change the text of my HTML code. it works if I put it at the HTML file, but not if I put in an external one.

The one that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="Monkey">Monkey</p>
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#Monkey").innerHTML="NoMoreMonkeys";
    </script>
     </body>

</html
```

Output: NoMoreMonkeys

The one that doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="hello.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="Monkey">Monkey</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

File "hello.js" :

```
document.querySelector("#Monkey").innerHTML="NoMoreMonkeys";
```

Output: Monkey

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include js before end of body,

because if js run before DOM ready, `#Monkey` did not exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <p id="Monkey">Monkey</p>
   <script src="hello.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or use `jquery` document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.querySelector("#Monkey").innerHTML="NoMoreMonkeys";
});
```

Comment: Also make sure they're in same directory/path

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to manipulate the page, when it is safe to do.
For that add jQuery to your page and let your JS code execute, when thh document is ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   document.querySelector("#Monkey").innerHTML="NoMoreMonkeys";
});
```

or select element with jQuery as well:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#Monkey" ).html("NoMoreMonkeys");
});
```